# how to get a family of measures from continuous conditional expectation

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory

I just realised I've been thinking about conditional expectation in a fallacious way:  I've been assuming that the continuous case follows the discrete case in the sense that for probability space $(X,\mu)$, and measurable $T: X\rightarrow \mathbb R$,  the function $$L^1(X,\mu) \rightarrow \mathbb R,~~~~ f\mapsto \mathbb E_\mu[~f~| ~t ~] $$ is a measure for $T_\ast \mu$-almost every $t\in \mathbb R$.  But of course this doesn't really make sense since in order to define $\mathbb E_\mu[~f~| ~t ~]$ you have to take a radon Nikodym derivative that depends on $f$, and that derivative is only defined up to a set of measure zero. So we have a possibly different null set for every $f\in L^1$.

**Presumably this factorisation can be rescued in some way with the right assumptions, though. What's the best way to do that?** I'm particularly interested in the case where $T$ is a sufficient statistic for a family of $\mu_\theta : \theta \in \Theta$, so then there are even more annoying null sets if one wants to make a family of measures $$\{f\mapsto \mathbb{E}_{\Theta}[f,t]: t\in \mathbb{R}\}.$$

Comment: How can a function $L^1\to\mathbb R$ be a measure?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question completely, but have you ever heard of a regular conditional probability?

Comment: @aduh no im pretty new to this stuff. ill look it up

Comment: @aduh yeah I think the regular conditional probability is the family of measures im looking for. ive read a couple of sources now for "regular conditional probability" but no one mentions an existence proof.  I have to think that in the general setting their existence is proved by taking a radon Nikodym derivative?

Comment: @JackM if the function satisfies certain properties, linearity, positivity, etc you can just take $\nu(A):=$ value of $\mathbb{1}_A$

Comment: @Timkinsella Existence of regular versions isn't guaranteed by Radon-Nikodym alone. You need some additional assumptions, about either the background measurable space (e.g. that it is a Polish space) or the conditioning sigma-field (e.g. that it is generated by a countable partition). I know that this topic is addressed in the probability books by Durrett, Billingsley, and Dudley. I expect it is covered in most graduate-level probability textbooks.

Comment: @aduh Ok thanks, I think this may answer my question.  I'll look at Billingsley